# Cypher regular expression error

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I'm running the following cypher query with a regex on my Neo4J database which should normally work without a problem but yet produces an error. Anyone has any idea what is wrong with this query? I'm using Neo4J 2.0.1

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name =~ 'Foo.*'
RETURN n;

> Expected 2013167 to be a java.lang.String, but it was a java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: Doesn't the error message say exactly what went wrong ? I think it should be researchable with this hint.

Comment: I tried running a slightly modified version of your query on my dataset and it worked fine.  Do you have any cases where the .name property was stored as an integer somewhere?

Comment: Can you try if this works? Then you would have to fix that one property: MATCH (n)
WHERE str(n.name) =~ 'Foo.*'
RETURN n;

Comment: Any idea how I can query Neo4J for all nodes with a .name property of a give type?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but that 2013167 number, is that referencing the internal id of the node? If so, can you grab that specific node and look at its properties to make sure the name property is not a type of integer?

Comment: No it's not referencing an internal node id `START n=node(2013167) RETURN n` returns zero nodes

Comment: See Michael hunger's comment